# ranking in Apache Pig

Tags: apache-pig

Is there a good way to do ranking on a column in Apache Pig after you've sorted it? Even better would be if the ranking handled ties.

```
A = LOAD 'file.txt' as (score:int, name:chararray);
B = foreach A generate score, name order by score;
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the Rank operation

```
A = load 'data' AS (f1:chararray,f2:int,f3:chararray);

DUMP A;
(David,1,N)
(Tete,2,N)
B = rank A;

dump B;
(1,David,1,N)
(2,Tete,2,N)
```

Reference https://blogs.apache.org/pig/entry/apache_pig_it_goes_to

Comment: It does handle ties.  Both Rank and Dense Rank are supported.  Reference: https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/basic.html#rank  `C = rank A by f1 DESC, f2 ASC;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use "ORDER BY" operator. And here is the [link](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/basic.html#order-by)

```
B = ORDER A BY score DESC;
```

or

```
B = ORDER A BY score ASC;
```

Comment: no, thats not the same thing - its just the first step. if you take say sprinter's times and order them in asc order than you can see you came in 1st, 2nd, 3rd, ect. but its another step to actually say for an instance - you were the 2nd smallest value.

Comment: Could you please post an example so that the requirement is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a mix of both the solutions

```
B = ORDER A BY score DESC;
C = rank B;
```

Lets say you want the second largest

```
D = filter C by $0 == 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rank in PIG and it will handle also ties, but it will use only one reducer while applying rank ,so performance will impact.

Comment: Can you give an example/demonstrate this with code? It's unclear how helpful the answer is without it being put in practice.